# como puedo hacer para que cuando ingrese el usuario y contraseña en los jtextfield compruebe si es correcto con los usuarios que están en el arraylist

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola! disculpen soy nueva, como puedo hacer para que cuando ingrese el usuario y contraseña en los jtextfield compruebe si es correcto con los usuarios que estan guardados en el arraylist? gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supongo que ya es tarde, pero una manera de comprobar si esta registrado es crear un método que recorra la lista y compruebe si existe un objeto Usuario con el mismo nombre y la misma contraseña, te muestro el código:

```
private ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

// TUS CAMPOS DE REGISTRO DE LA INTERFAZ
private JTextField nombre;
private JTextField clave; // JPasswordField

public void botonAceptar() {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario(nombre.getText(), clave.getText());
    if(isRegistered(usuario)){
        System.out.println("El usuario ya esta registrado");
    }else {
        usuarios.add(usuario);
        System.out.println("El usuario se ha registrado");
    }
}

private boolean isRegistered(Usuario usuario) {
    for(Usuario users : usuarios) {
        if(users.getName().equals(usuario.getName())){
            if(users.getPassword() == usuario.getPassword()){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Entonces cada vez que agregas mas usuarios y presionas al botón de aceptar, recorre la lista de usuarios y comprueba si ya existe un objeto Usuario con el mismo nombre y contraseña, si no es así, se agrega el usuario a la lista